Convergence of weighted sum to Brownian Motion
Let $\{\varepsilon_t\}_{t = 1}^T$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $\varepsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2 > 0$. Then it is known that (see 17.3.6 in James Hamilton's Time Series Analysis)
$T^{-1/2}\sum_{t = 1}^{[sT]}\varepsilon_t \to \sigma B(s)$,
where $s \in [0, 1]$, $[sT]$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $sT$, and $B(s)$ is a standard brownian motion. The convergence is weak and follows by the functional central limit theorem. What would the corresponding statement look like for
$T^{-1/2}\sum_{t = 1}^{[sT]}w_t\varepsilon_t$,
where $\{w_t\}_{t = 1}^T$ is some sequence. What conditions need to be placed on this sequence?
My conjecture is that
$T^{-1/2}\sum_{t = 1}^{[sT]}w_t\varepsilon_t \to \lambda B(s)$,
where $\lambda = \sigma \sqrt{\sum_{t = 1}^\infty w_t^2}$, so that the required condition would be $\sum_{t = 1}^\infty w_t^2 < \infty$. However, I am not familiar enough with the concepts to show it.
I know this discussion is not fully formal. I am only looking for references, and likewise informal answers. Thanks in advance!

First observe that with $s=1$, we should have the convergence of variances hence
$$
L^2:=\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac 1T\sum_{t=1}^Tw_t^2
$$
exists. Second, the increments in $s$ of the process $T^{-1/2}\sum_{t = 1}^{[sT]}w_t\varepsilon_t$ are orthogonal, hence the finite dimensional distributions of this process converge to those of $L\sigma B(s)$.
Probably more work is required for the tightness in $D([0,1])$.
